# Calculation based on actual value

Tags: r, plyr

I'd like to excuse in advance for the title which is probably off target, but the very reason I'm asking this question is because I couldn't frame the question.

So I have the following dataframe:

```
id date  result winning streak
x1 22/09 1
x1 20/10 0
x1 28/10 1
x1 02/11 1      month total
```

I would like to calculate some kind of month total. So in this example I would like to have the month total for x1 on 02/11. This is the sum of the result on 20/10 and 28/10 (so 0 + 1 = 1). 22/09 isn't included because that date is more than a month away from 02/11. This seems like a simple question. Normally I use plyr for these kinds of things but the fact that the calculation changes based on the date confuses me.

The actual dataframe has about 5k entries so the solution should be generalizable.

Comment: Have you tried `aggregate()`?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for something like `with(df, tapply(result, substr(date, 4, 5), sum))`, though your column names are badly defined

Comment: As I understand aggregate does the same things as plyr. I needed something more dynamic (which changes for each value). Thanks to both of you but the solution David gave is what I was looking for.